# Building .appx of Debug in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal, solution, appx

I have a solution for UWP application in Visual Studio 2015
and see that there is file named "ProjectName_1.0.17.0_x86_Debug.appx" in "ProjectName\bin\x86\Debug" directory.

I don't remember how I build it. How could I build a new version of this file?
"Build solution" and "Deploy solution" is not a solution. :)

Comment: there is a solution to execute from development console:
`makeappx pack /l /d bin/x86/Debug/AppX /p bin/x86/Debug/ProjectName_x86_Debug.appx`
`signtool sign /a /v /fd SHA256 /f ProjectName_StoreKey.pfx bin/x86/Debug/ProjectName_x86_Debug.appx`

but is there an ability to do so from visual studio interface?

Comment: You may store (right click on project) the appx bundle in debug mode. If you just build it - you may find your last build in "ProjectName\bin\x86\Debug" directory.

Comment: Right click on project -> "Store" -> "Create App Packages..." creates only Release packages, but I need a Debug package. How to do it?

Comment: debug appx is created every time you run your project with Debug setting and proper architecture set, so just select Debug, Local Machine, x86 target and launch debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem myself. Really one should do the following steps: 
Right click on project in Solution explorer -> "Store" -> "Create App Packages..." 
And then one should choose "No" as an answer for a question "Do you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Store?"
[image]
In case you'll select "Yes" there will no possibility to choose Debug for packaging, but in case of "No" there is such possibility:
[image]